# Run and stop a function from thread using Tkinter button

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I want the method `tryme` to run only when I push the "snackPlay" button in the gui, but it runs as soon as I run the script. What can I do to make `tryme` run only on command?
Thanks.

```
import threading
from Tkinter import *
from tkSnack import *


class MyThread ( threading.Thread ):

   def tryme ( self ):

      print 'up uP UP'                

root = Tk()
initializeSnack(root)

f = Frame(root)
f.pack()
Button(f, bitmap='snackPlay', command=MyThread().tryme()).pack(side='left')
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot about threading, but you should try `command = MyThread().tryme` instead of `command = MyThread().tryme()` (it works for me after I remove all the `tkSnack` stuff).

Tkinter callbacks expect *callable objects*, not function *results*.

Comment: @user1627762 -- not sure (Like I said, I don't do much threading).  I would guess that you could add a boolean attribute to `MyThread` which is initialized to `False` and then break from your loop whenever it switches to `True`.  Then add a second button which toggles that attribute.  But like I said, that's just a guess.